# configuration in iOS MDM

Tags: ios, configuration-files, mdm

I'm reading some docs about MDM.
According to "Moile device management protocol" document, server can set config for managed devices by installing profile files onto devices. Things that can config in that file are described in 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iphoneconfigurationprofileref/Introduction/Introduction.html.
My Questions are:

- if server install 2 profiles that have different config for the same thing, what will happen?
- "Moile device management protocol" documents also mention about "Managed App Configuration and Feedback". So what is different between the previous config file with this function of server.
- Is "Managed App Configuration and Feedback" just for specific app, not for the whole device as profile files.
- which fields can be config via "Managed App Configuration and Feedback" of MDM?

Thank all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if server install 2 profiles that have different config for the same thing, what will happen?

good question.

First of all, I don't think there are that my things which can be contradictorily. Also, it make sense to build your server that way that you don't have situation.

It's not documented what happens, so you will rely on undocumented behavior. I would really recommend resolve conflicts on the server and send only one type of configuration.

My guess would be that the first or last configuration will be applied (if they are contradictorily).

> Is "Managed App Configuration and Feedback" just for specific app

There are two things:

- Configuration profiles (these are settings which are sent to a device and configure the whole device or account for the whole device). There is a defined list of these.
- Managed App configuration (these are settings which are sent to some particular application. There is no defined list of these, you can specify your own.